# C# EmptyIfNull extension for any IEnumerable to return empty derived type

Tags: c#

Assuming nulls and empty collections are equivalent, I'm trying to write an extension method for IEnumerable types to return empty collections of the derived type instead of null. This way I don't have to repeat null checks all over the place, and I don't get an IEnumerable back that I have to cast.

e.g.

```
List<Foo> MethodReturningFooList()
{
...
}

Foo[] MethodReturningFooArray()
{
...
}

void Bar()
{
    List<Foo> list = MethodReturningFooList().EmptyIfNull();
    Foo[] arr = MethodReturningFooArray().EmptyIfNull();
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static T EmptyIfNull<T>(this T iEnumerable)
        where T : IEnumerable, new()
    {
        var newTypeFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.New(typeof(T))).Compile();
        return iEnumerable == null ? newTypeFunc() : iEnumerable;
    }
}
```

This extension seems to work, but does anyone see any pitfalls?

Comment: IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> are not the same thing.

Comment: You're compiling a new method each time you call `EmptyIfNull`. You can simply do `return iEnumerable == null ? Activator.CreateInstance<T>() : iEnumerable;`

Comment: I was avoiding Activator for performance reasons. The compiled methods could be cached, but this portion is not the main concern.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but I was recently pinged on it. I noticed now that you've added the : new() constraint, the method can simply be `return iEnumerable ?? new T()`

Comment: @Rob I did not realize this at the time. I believe this should be the answer (without having tested it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it will break in this case:

```
IEnumerable<int> test = null;
var result = test.EmptyIfNull();
```

You can solve it like this:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static List<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        return list ?? new List<T>();
    }
    public static T[] EmptyIfNull<T>(this T[] arr)
    {
        return arr ?? new T[0];
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {   
        return enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

You'll need overloads to make sure you're returning the same collection type (as you were before).

Here's an example of a case that *can't* work by returning the same collection type:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return tempList.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return tempList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

MyAbstractClass myClass = null;
MyAbstractClass instance = myClass.EmptyIfNull();
```

There's no way we can return a `MyAbstractClass` here without knowing about subclasses. And with a null reference, that's not possible without guessing. Further, what happens when classes do not have a default constructor? Getting into dangerous territory.

You'll need to either have a catch-all `IEnumerable<T>` return, and have the user cast it, or provide overloads as I've shown above

Comment: The code doesn't break if variable is null, he check if variable is null first.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro No, it breaks because the type is `IEnumerable<int>` and cannot be constructed

Comment: Yeah, forgot this detail.

Comment: That is the best way, nice answer Rob!!

Comment: I updated my question and added new() to address the new IEnumerable<T> case

Comment: @JonWong That will fix the issue where you get an error, but my example will still fail to compile

Comment: @Rob Got it... That's ok for my needs--as long as it tells you up front.

Comment: @Rob, I would just use `Array.Empty<T>()` instead of `new T[0]` for perf. and memory usage reasons. You can't foresee how often these utility methods end up being called.

Answer (score 4):

I just should improve this like that

```
public static class Extension 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> iEnumerable) 
    { 
        return iEnumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

Or better with C# 6

```
public static class Extension 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> iEnumerable) 
        => iEnumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: Note that as [Rob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34646103/477420) shows this code is very different from OP's one - it only works for `IEnumerable<T>` (which indeed what most of code should be using), but fails for test cases shown in the post where type of collection is preserved (whether it is good idea or not could be separate discussion).

Answer (score 0):

A method that I get a generic parameter (with the restriction of being a class because I will create a instance of this type). Then I define a default object at runtime, and check if the object received by parameter is null, if the object is null I return the object that was instantiated at runtime otherwise return the object itself passed by parameter.

I hope that helps

```
    public static T EmptyIfNull<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {           
        var objNotNull = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        if (obj == null)
            return objNotNull as T;

        return obj;
    }
```

**Unit Test :**

[image]

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue