# c# what object literal could stop a foreach loop from looping?

Tags: c#, foreach, null-object-pattern

I know I could wrap the entire foreach loop in an if statement, but I'm wondering if there's some object literal value replacement for `new List<string>()` so that the foreach skips executing when myList is null?  In Javascript I could simply put `[]` after a coalesce to refer to an empty set that would stop the foreach loop.

```
List<string> myList = null;

foreach (var i in myList ?? new List<string>() )
    i.Dump();
```

Unnecessary background information that does not change the answer:
`List<Entity>()` is my actual list that comes from ASP.NET MVC data binding, so I don't control creating it.  I used the Entity Framework database models (POCOs) as an input to the Controller method like you would use a control function, setting parameters of the function to flow data to a table.  The POCO comes from the database, so I don't control that either.

Just looking for some sort of empty object literal I could use to avoid running the loop without creating a new object.

I really think it's a C# flaw to throw an exception when myList is null.  If it's null, there's nothing to do, so the loop should skip over.

Comment: Use [`Enumerable.Empty<string>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @dbc That worked.  post the answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks

Comment: Or see [C# EmptyIfNull extension for any IEnumerable to return empty derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34645963/3744182) or [Linq method to transform nulls into empty IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115524) if you need to make this check often.

Comment: @dbc you have a lot of hats

Comment: I just initialize my lists to new List<string>(); in my model's constructors. It assures me that I don't have a null value.

Comment: *I really think it's a C# flaw to throw an exception when myList is null.* - I tend to agree.  I once had to fix a performance issue with dynamically updating a complex CAD model (200k+ geometric objects) where a measurable amount of time was spent counting many, many empty collections.  By "measurable" I mean 1/40th of a second -- but the update had to be completed in 1/4 of a second so the time spent counting the collections, though a small part of the problem, actually mattered.  But my experience is sort of unusual.

Comment: @Gilles unfortunately ASP.NET's data binding feeds the data to me.  I don't think it executes constructor methods at least in this sense to set them to empty lists.

Comment: I really wish negative feedback was accompanied with an explanation from a named author.  This answer actually solved my problem, was valuable to me, and probably valuable to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Empty<string>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx).

See *[C# EmptyIfNull extension for any IEnumerable to return empty derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34645963/3744182)* or *[Linq method to transform nulls into empty IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115524)* for extension methods you could use if you need to make this check often.